# How to fetch last 24 hours record from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have checked similar questions on the site but I'm unable to understand how exactly it works. In my database, I have 3 columns - `id`, `name` and `password`. What do I need to add to my database and how can I get the last 24 hours records?

```
mysql_query("select * from core With-in the last 24 hours");
```

Comment: Maybe you can use some of those similar questions and show us your attempts, or at least link to one and explain what you don't understand about it.

Comment: what is the working of this= date_field > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a column *ts* to your table

```
ALTER TABLE core 
ADD COLUMN ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Which is a timestamp and is automatically set to the current time on the machine every time you insert or update a row.
You can then do

```
SELECT id, name, password FROM core
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ts, NOW()) < 24;
```

And it should return entries added or updated within the last 24 hours.

Comment: i add a column in database name date where i store the date is this format 2013-12-22 23:09:24 . now what to do with query

Comment: If the column is of type DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, you can use it with TIMESTAMPDIFF(). Just replace _ts_ with the name of your date-keeping column.

Comment: i am confused with timestamp .acctully in my db i have id,name,password and date(type=varchar). now what i have to add to get the last 24 hrs record only ..and thanks you so much for you quick reply

Comment: You can use STR_TO_DATE() to convert your varchar, i.e. use the SELECT query written in my original answer above and replace _ts_ with :  
STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')

Comment: fine . i update the date(type= date) in db.
now i used your query ..like this= $new=mysql_query("SELECT id, name, password FROM core
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ts, NOW()) >= 24");
$n=mysql_fetch_row($new);
echo $n[1];
it returns error to me (boolean error)

Comment: i change the date column name to ts in db . and change the type varchar to date. m=now my db contains id,password,email,ts(type=date).
now what code need to use after this query.i mean now how to fetch the records

Comment: Sorry. I made an error in the sql query. It should be TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ts, NOW()) < 24 instead, to give only the recent 24 hours of records. Also, you should use type DATETIME instead of DATE, since the latter does not store time and thus you will not get records from the last 24 hours but only records changed by the current date. The boolean error sounds like a php error. Try and read your error logs to debug it.   
Also, STR_TO_DATE format is slightly off. It should be STR_TO_DATE(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s').

Answer (score 1):

You should add 1 more column to hold date. Next you can use this column to select data:

```
mysql_query("select * from `core` where date_field > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR");
```

Comment: what is the working of this= date_field > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR"

Comment: date_field - field you use to keep date, you can change it to `ts`. I assume `ts` is the name of your date field.
`mysql_query("select * from \`core\` where \`ts\` > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR");`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
date_time_value +|- INTERVAL n DAY|HOUR|MONTH etc.
For me it's the better way to express to add or substract time span from the specified time.

Comment: ok fine. i use this query now but the problem is the output is empty.
i used= $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM core WHERE time_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR)")or die(mysql_error());

$result=mysql_fetch_row($query);
print_r($query);
echo $result[1];
// time_date is db table column name and type is date..thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your problem please try executing following code snippet

```
  mysql_query("select * from `core` where  HOUR(TIMEDIFF( NOW( ) ,  field ))<=24 );
```

For more details about **TIMEDIFF** function  please refer the documentation in following url

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
SELECT * 
FROM core
WHERE DATE(Time) = DATE(CAST(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS DATE))
```

Comment: i add a column in database name date where i store the date is this format 2013-12-22 23:09:24 .
now what to do with query