# How to show 'NEW' tag after updating category recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I show `NEW` tag after updating category from database. Like this image [image: see this image]

Only after if my category get Updated and show for 24 hrs.

This is my Adapter of Categories

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.viewHolder> {

    ArrayList<RecipeModels> list;
    Context context;

    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<RecipeModels> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_set,parent,false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        RecipeModels models = list.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(models.getPic());
        holder.textView.setText(models.getText());

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            // It is sending data to category activity.
            //Intent intent = new Intent(context, CategoryActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("title",fruits.get(position).getTitle());
            //intent.putExtra("name", fruits.get(position).getName());
            //context.startActivity(intent);
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public static class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any idea to do this. Any Idea or code to implement this? I can add more code if you want, but please help to solve this issue!

Comment: Do you receive data from a server or just locally?

Comment: @MouaadAbdelghafourAITALI from server

Comment: Is the data poll from server async process (via some on device service) or is it only fetched when you start the app?

Comment: @AbhirojPanwar Yes, it fetching only when the app starts. Data is fetching to app through API when app starts. So that when data updated on the server, it gets updated in the user's mobile. But I want to show update tag "NEW" on the outside category when data is updated so that the user can understand that the data has been updated. I do not understand the logic of this, how can it be done?

Comment: Question is not crafted well. Reader needs to assume a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply query your data layer for `lastUpdated <= now() - 24hrs` window. All the responses from DB would be `new` elements only.

If you want distinction b/w new and old data within 1 result set, you can use `if-else` in the query to set a boolean flag `isNew`. basically, something like

```
select D.id, (IF D.lastUpdated >= now() - 24hrs THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS isNew from table D;
```

where

```
LastUpdated is a column on table D of type timestamp.

And is filled by application while writing the data to DB.
```

This should better to offload on DB, rather than App, since DB can use indexes to do this filter rather quick.

### The above answer assumes there is a DB associated with app

If that's not the case, you can't do this labelling since you app does not have any state to compute the diff with. All vectors are filled only when app starts

Comment: Yeah, this is correct that my app fetches data when it opens. And problem is that an app does not have any method to store the current state of data because an app fetches data every time when user opens it. This method will be correct if I implement this in my DB.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable Idea. I just needed an idea that how to implement it. Finally, your idea given me a flying wing. I got my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20732245/16765223

Answer (score 0):

You can use DiffUtils in your adapter to get the Changed/Updated data.Based on that, you can set the visibility of  "New" tag from your card.

```
 class​ ​CategoriesAdapter​(): BaseAdapter<Category>( 
 diffCallback = ​object​ : ​DiffUtil​.​ItemCallback​<​Category​>() 
 { 
   override​ fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: ​Category​, newItem: ​Category​): ​Boolean​ {
      TODO​("​Not​ yet implemented") 
     } 

   override​ fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: ​Category​, newItem: ​Category​): ​Boolean​ { 
         ​TODO​("​Not​ yet implemented")                      } 

 }) { }
```

This is how your Base Adapter's declaration will look like:

```
 abstract​ ​class​ ​BaseAdapter​<​T​>( 
 diffCallback​:​ ​DiffUtil​.​ItemCallback​<​T​>) 
 :​ ​ListAdapter​<​T​, ​BaseViewHolder​>( 
 AsyncDifferConfig​.​Builder​<​T​>(diffCallback) 
 .setBackgroundThreadExecutor(​Executors​.newSingleThreadExecutor())   
 .build() 
 ) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to try this method to implement.

Comment: Not solved yet,

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try and get a timestamp for each image from the server.

Then, compare it to the android system's current time.

Using an if else statement, if the time gap is within the 24 hour range, display the 'new' label. or else, set it to View.GONE.

Now, If that's not possible, You would have to create a database within the app itself which also creates its own time stamp of the images.

Then compare for each image and display label when necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I got my answer from your second method. But using `SELECT id, name, password FROM core
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, ts, NOW()) < 24;` method